# Add custom block in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9 I want to add a custom block to the homepage, but nothing happens. I have these files:

app/design/frontend/[mytheme]/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" as="customblock" translate="label">
                <label>Custom Block</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="customblockreference">
            <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

In homepage.phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customblock') ?>
```

in
app/design/frontend/[mytheme]/default/template/customblock.phtml

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to put the name of the block displayed via `homepage.phtml` in the name attribute of your reference node. But since `homepage.phtml` is not something coming from a stock Magento, there is not much we can do to help if you do not provide us at least the layout where this parent block is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `homepage.phtml` is the root template you are using for the home page, so please clarify if that is not the case.

I think the problem is that the `core/text_list` block `customblock` is getting rendered in your root template `homepage.phtml` but you have not added anything to that block. The `core/text_list` is just a container which renders child blocks that are added to it.

It seems like you might be trying to add `customblock.phtml` to the new `core/text_list`, if that is the case it should be something like this:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" translate="label">
        <label>Custom Block</label>
        <block type="core/template" name="customblock-child" template="customblock.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

That will add the child template block directly to the `core/text_list` since you are just defining both here in the same file. However, if you needed to add a new block to that `core/text_list` from elsewhere, you could do it like this:

```
<reference name="customblock">
    <block type="core/template" name="customblock-child" template="customblock.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: I have tried to change the block name from `customblock` to `customblockreference` like the reference name, and it works, the block is display in the home, but i don't know if this is the better way to do that

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to fantasticrice's a answer. If you are calling this within an XML file. You only need to reference the HomePage CMS page.. You can do this by using the handle `<cms_index_index>`which is the homepage.

```
<!-- Homepage -->
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" translate="label">
            <label>Custom Block</label>
            <block type="core/template" name="customblock-child" template="customblock.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: But if replace `<default>` with `<cms_index_index>` the block can be add only in homepage, not in other part of the template, doesn't it?

Comment: Correct. Cms index is homepage cms only

Answer (score 0):

You should define your module on app/etc/modules , if the module its created you should see in admin site (on web) configuration > advance , and check if the module its activated

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <your_module>   <!-- Name of Module -->
        <active>true</active>  <!-- This says if the module is active or not -->
        <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- This says the location of the module i.e inside the local folder. It can also be community folder. -->
    </your_module>
</modules>
```

And remember that your own implementations should be located on the local codepool , core codepool its for magento dev. of course you can extend the functionallity in local

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. `local.xml` is a layout file that can work in any theme of Magento without a need to be declared. [source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento)

Answer (score 0):

**My solution**

I replaced from file:
`app/design/frontend/[mytheme]/default/layout/local.xml`

this:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" as="customblock" translate="label">
     <label>Custom Block</label>
</block>
```

to:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="customblockreference" translate="label">
     <label>Custom Block</label>
</block>
```

so, now it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="root">
         <block type="core/text_list" name="customblockreference" translate="label">
              <label>Custom Block</label>
         </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="customblockreference">
        <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

And  `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customblock') ?>` from the page homepage.phtml become `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customblockreference') ?>`

Comment: This is the same as my solution, except you used different names. Also, I would still define `customblock` directly inside `customblockreference` as there is no reason to use a `reference` when you are defining both blocks right here in the same file.

Comment: You are right, your solution is easier. So how you already said this part     `<reference name="customblockreference">
        <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
    </reference>`
is useful only if i need to add a block in `customblockreference` in some other .xml file, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose for `reference`